# Bayesian method: which part is hard to evaluate in Bayesian inference

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian

I have a question about posterior inference in Bayes.

In Bayesian inference, suppose we are given a model p(x|\theta) and a prior distribution p(\theta), we observed the dataset D ={x_1,x_2,...,x_N}, the goal is to estimate the usually intractable posterior p(\theta|D).

Sometimes I find some ones choose to evaluate the joint p(\theta,D) because this joint distribution is proportional to posterior p(\theta|D) = p(\theta,D)/p(D), what is the reason behind this? Isn't p(D) is hard to evaluate?  Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to maximise p(θ|D) by finding the optimal parameters \theta.

This can be rewritten as argmax P( θ | D) P(D)

However, P(D) is independent of θ. Hence you can ignore it or in readable mathematical notation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bayes' Theorem can be expressed as p(T|x) = p(T,X)/p(X) = p(x|T)p(T)/p(X), for observed data X and parameters T.

p(x|T) is often referred to as the "likelihood" component of the model - if you specify the model, this is computationally easy.  Similarly, p(T) gives the model priors, which you specify.

You're right, the denominator p(X) is a mess, but as @CAFEBABE points out, it's independent of parameters T, so it's functionally a constant.  Thus, the distribution of the posterior is often simplified as p(T|x) proportional to p(x|T)p(T).

Comment: to clarify, this simplification (that is, p(T|x) is proportional to p(x|T)p(T)) is just that: a simplification. 

as such, it is almost useless for practical applications, where integration over the posterior distribution is the ultimate goal.